# Which Ubuntu version on Imac G5

Tags: system-installation, mac

Which version of Ubuntu can i install on my imac G5 Power PC.

It has 1 GB RAM, Power PC 1,6 processor, and nVidia GeForce FX 5200.

14.04 Trusty Tahr will be ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Trusty Tahr (14.04) doesn't work on G5 (PPC).

You need 12.04 (Precise Pangolian). The downloads are [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/), and the precise file you need is [this one (direct download from the Ubuntu website)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso).

Comment: Ok, i have one more Question. What about a graphic drivers on this distribution - 12.04 (Precise Pangolian). There is a lot of info that there are some graphics glitches whith this old graphic card (A specially on Debian). Is Ubuntu 12.04 free of this problems.